# How can I edit the kwargs of a RedirectView?

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views

I have a project that needs to redirect legacy urls to the new urls (I need to keep them for a while)...
I'm using the RedirectView class to do this, but I have to set up the url hard-coded.

My code is like this:

```
class LegacyParlamentarDetailRedirectView(RedirectView):
    permanent = True
    url = '/parlamentar/%s'
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        pk = request.GET.get('cod_parlamentar', '')
        self.url = self.url % (pk)

        return super(LegacyParlamentarDetailRedirectView, self).get(self, request, *args, **kwargs)
```

What I want to do is to use the pattern_name attribute so I do not have to write the url, but I need to add the variable pk to the kwargs list (something like this):

```
class LegacyParlamentarDetailRedirectView(RedirectView):
    permanent = True
    pattern_name = 'parlamentar_detail'
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['pk'] = request.GET.get('cod_parlamentar', '')

        return super(LegacyParlamentarDetailRedirectView, self).get(self, request, *args, )
```

can anyone help me?

Comment: I would comment out `permanent = True` until you are sure that the redirects are working. You don't want your browser to store incorrect redirects.

Comment: @Alasdair, I change the value to False whenever I test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You include `self` in the method signature, but not when you call the method.

If you want to add `pk` to the existing kwargs, then you should do:

```
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    kwargs['pk'] = request.GET.get('cod_parlamentar', '')
    return super(LegacyParlamentarDetailRedirectView, self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

If you want to ignore existing kwargs then you should change it to:

```
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    kwargs = {'pk': request.GET.get('cod_parlamentar', '')}
    return super(LegacyParlamentarDetailRedirectView, self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Note that you'll need to handle errors when `cod_parlamentar` is missing from the GET params.

From the code you have shown, I think it would be clearer if you overrode `get_redirect_url` instead:

```
from django.urls import reverse
# from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse # Django 1.9 and earlier

class LegacyParlamentarDetailRedirectView(RedirectView):
    permanent = True

    def get_redirect_url(self):
        return reverse('parlamentar_detail', kwargs={'pk': self.request.GET.get('cod_parlamentar', ''})
```

Comment: your last solution satisfy my needs ( using `get_redirect_url`). I just had to change `request.GET.get` to `self.request.get.get` and it worked perfectly.

Comment: Please correct this so I can accept your response, please.

Comment: Good spot, fixed :)